# How to prevent a user from circumventing the process of steps that must be followed?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a multi form wizard, with several steps that must be completed, this script has been developed very different from the normal ones, my script avoids that the data filled by the user is lost and it avoids losing the step of the user.

The steps of the script are saved in a session that avoids returning to the beginning, keeping them always in the current step of the user.

But I have a vulnerability problem in the process of the steps that must be followed.

If a malicious user changes the values of the URL, in the following way:

```
localhost/wizard/saveTemp.php?step=6
```

That user can skip the steps at your will.

Example the user is in step 1, but I modify the url and automatically jump to step 6.

So how can I prevent them from teasing the system by adding a strengthened control with PHP, where a user can not jump from step 1 to step 3 or step 6, but must continue the order of steps 1,2,3,4,5 , 6 and so on.

**My Script Wizard**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
  session_destroy();
  session_start();
}
?>

<script>
var currentStep =  <?php echo $step ?>; // Variable indicating the current step, data selected with PHP sessions
var radio = <?php echo $radio ?>; //Value of the radius selected

function show_step(step) {
    var data = $("#form").serialize();
    var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
    var valid = true;

    // [OPTIONAL] Validate only if you are going forward
    if (currentStep < step) {

      // We search all the fields within the current step.
      $('#step' + currentStep).find('input,textarea,select').each((idx, el) => {
        let $field = $(el);
        let $fieldCont = $field.closest('.form-group');

        // If the field is a checkbox or a radio and an option was not selected
        if (($field.prop('type') == 'checkbox' || $field.prop('type') == 'radio') &&
            !$fieldCont.find('input[name="'+$field.prop('name')+'"]:checked').length) {
          $fieldCont.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        }
        // If the field is NOT a checkbox or a radio and is empty
        else if ($field.prop('type') != 'checkbox' && $field.prop('type') != 'radio' &&
          !$field.val()) {
          $fieldCont.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        } else {
          $fieldCont.removeClass('error');
        }
      });
    }

    // If at least one field was not completed
    if (!valid) {
      return;
    }

    //
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    }).done(function(resp){
      $('#radio').val(resp.radio);

      if (step === 2) {
        var radio = parseInt(resp.radio);
        switch(radio) {
          case 1:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal.php'
            break;
          case 2:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal2.php'
            break;
          case 3:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal3.php'
            break;
          default:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal4.php'
            break;

        }

 $('#divPay').load(urlform,function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
          if(statusTxt === "success") {

            $('#step' + currentStep).css("display", "none");
            $('#step' + step).fadeIn("slow");
            currentStep = step;
          }
          if(statusTxt === "error") {
            //
          }
        });
      } else {

        $('#step' + currentStep).css("display", "none");
        $('#step' + step).fadeIn("slow");
        currentStep = step;
      }
    });
  };

  $(function() {
    show_step(currentStep);
    $('a.next').click(e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      show_step(currentStep + 1);
    });

    $('a.back').click(e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      show_step(currentStep - 1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML structure**

```
<form id="form">
  <div id="step1" class="step">
    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <a href="#back" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">
    <h1>Step 3</h1>
    <a href="#back" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step4" class="step">
    <h1>Step 3</h1>
    <a href="#back" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step5" class="step">
    <h1>Step 3</h1>
    <a href="#back" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step6" class="step">
    <h1>Step 4</h1>
    <a href="#back" class="back">back</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**saveTemp.php** *Or it is possible to receive the steps by POST method instead of the GET method, thus avoiding changes in the URL `(saveTemp.php? Step = 6)`*

```
<?php
session_start();

$step =  isset($_GET['step']) ?  $_GET['step'] : 1;

// We save the form data in a session variable
$_SESSION['data_form'] = $_POST;
// we also add the step to the array, you can not use this name (__step__) as name in the form

$dataForm = (isset($_SESSION['data_form']) && is_array($_SESSION['data_form'])) ? $_SESSION['data_form'] :array();

$sStep = isset($dataForm['__step__']) ? $dataForm['__step__'] : 1;
$step = isset($step) ? $step : $sStep;

$radio   = isset($dataForm['radio']) ? $dataForm['radio'] : 1;

$_SESSION['data_form']['__step__'] = $step;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json =  array(
  'radio'     => $radio,
  'step'      => $step
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Using the POST method doesn't help. The user can use Developer Tools to change the hidden input with the step number.

Comment: @Barmar Wow, I did not expect that, thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 13):

When you complete processing the form, put the step in a session variable. When you're processing the next submission, check that `$step` is the next step.

```
$last_step = isset($_SESSION['step']) ? $_SESSION['step'] : 0;
if ($step > $last_step + 1) {
    die("You can't jump directly from step $last_step to $step");
}
```

At the end of the script, once you've validated all the information, save the step in the session variable:

```
$_SESSION['step'] = $step;
```

Full code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$step =  isset($_GET['step']) ?  $_GET['step'] : 1;
$last_step = isset($_SESSION['data_form']['__step__']) ? $_SESSION['data_form']['__step__'] : 0;
if ($step > $last_step + 1) {
    die(json_encode(array('error' => 'Invalid step')));
}

// We save the form data in a session variable
$_SESSION['data_form'] = $_POST;
// we also add the step to the array, you can not use this name (__step__) as name in the form

$dataForm = (isset($_SESSION['data_form']) && is_array($_SESSION['data_form'])) ? $_SESSION['data_form'] :array();

$sStep = isset($dataForm['__step__']) ? $dataForm['__step__'] : 1;
$step = isset($step) ? $step : $sStep;

$radio   = isset($dataForm['radio']) ? $dataForm['radio'] : 1;

$_SESSION['data_form']['__step__'] = $step;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json =  array(
  'radio'     => $radio,
  'step'      => $step
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Friend does not work, just show me the error message.

Comment: Did you set the session variable properly? Did you do this after the code that does `$step = isset($_GET['step'])`?

Comment: And you do `$_SESSION['step'] = $step;` at the end of the script?

Comment: Would not it be easier to add the complete code of how it would be?

Comment: I don't understand `$step = isset($step) ? $step : $sStep;`. At the top of the script you always set `$step`, so `isset($step)` will always be false.

Comment: +1 now it works :) but I can not backtrack friend, if  back and reload the page it takes me directly to the step where the user arrived.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to backtrack.

Comment: If you go back, but you do not save the session of the steps back. Example I have completed all the steps from 1 to 4, but I'm going back to step 2, and when I reloaded the page, it returned me to step 4, and not step 2, which I backed down.

Comment: The question says "must continue the order of steps 1,2,3,4,5 , 6 and so on." Nothing about going backward there.

Comment: Anyway, if you want less restriction, it should be easy for you to modify the logic in the above code. Do you really need me to write the whole thing for you? Aren't you a programmer, can't you extrapolate from what I wrote?

Comment: Yes, in that sense of steps, but it is a multi-step wizard and you are not always going to follow steps forward you can go back to verify your information. And when going backwards, those backward steps are not saved in the session, devaluing my system.

Comment: I understand, then to the `if` an `else` is added instead of plus a minus 1, tell me if I am correct.

Comment: You can check `$step > $last_step + 1` instead of `!=`.

Comment: with that operator `>` works what did not work, but the validation of the url is lost, that is, I can modify the url

Comment: I don't understand. If you report error when `$step > $last_step + 1`, they can't jump from 1 to 3, but they can go back from 3 to 1. I've edited my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to simply don't do so.

I mean: I figure out you would also validate user inputs and don't permit users go ahead to next step if current one is not properly filled.

And I also figure out you validate inputs at least server side.

Having that no subforms would be valid by default (without any user input) or, if so, you can simply add a hidden input and fill it automatically on some event (such as form-step loaded); the only thing you need to do is to re-validate whole form (up to required step) every time any step is requested.

If client requests, for example, step 6 but step 5 was not validated, just send http-redirect header to step 5 and, optionally, some minimal html error suggesting to do just that and providing a link to do so manually.